# Make header content span to wrapper width

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper div that acts as a wrapper for the entire page.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <header id="page-header">
        <div id="header-left"></div>
        <div id="header-right"></div>
    </header>
    <section id="page-body"></section>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#wrapper{ 
    width: 1100px; /* Example / actually using media queries */ 
    margin: 0 auto; 
} 

#page-header{
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
}
```

What I'm interested in is having the `header-left` / `header-right` span according to the width of the wrapper element, and centering it accordingly without changing the HTML structure too much.

I cannot use the `inherit` property since that would inherit a 100% width of the header element, which is not preferrable (in my case).
I could create a separate wrapper for the header-left/right elements, but wondered if there is a shorter way that wouldn't require me to copy these formats for every media query, and leverage the benefit of having the wrapper.

Alternatively, just applying a class could also be an option.
Still, sort of feels to defeat the purpose of having a wrapper to manage the width.

Result example:

[image: example problem]

Currently I solved the problem by adding a class `wrapper` to the header-left/right. In case you have a better solution, be welcome.

Edit: link to codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGoYbE
The design looks shitty there, but it's enough to play with.

Comment: I think in future adding a fiddle or codepen or any sort of testing will allow us to play around and give more accurate feedback as a image makes it difficult for us so look and test different solutions.

Comment: @Torean Codepen added.

Comment: @KimGysen, First, it's not the best practice to use IDs in CSS (better use classes). Second, which effect are you trying to achieve? To have both header divs to have width of 50%? You may want to make one div of fixed size and the second one to take remaining width. But still, I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @WhiteAngel I used class `wrapper` instead of id, I guess it's ok. Regarding the `id` vs `class`, it is an opinion. I prefer to use id's to identify specific page sections that don't change. The effect I tried to achieve was already achieved, I was looking for a way to bypass the header width (100%), and align the inner divs to the width of the wrapper automagically. Whether or not float left / right are 50% is in this case trivial for me, is I would use nowrap anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how i would create the design you are describing:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
}
#page-header {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
}
#header-left {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 49%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 180px;
}
#header-right {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 180px;
}
#page-body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header id="page-header">
    <div id="content">
      <div id="header-left">Left lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
      <div id="header-right">lorem lorem lorem lorem Right</div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section id="page-body">BODY</section>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is not correct at all: please post a picture or a simple drawing of the design you are attempting.

Comment: Pic added in the question details.

Comment: +1 for a solution that works. I use mediaqueries to optimize the width at breakpoints with pixels though.

Comment: @KimGysen Code above should work with breakpoints since it uses relative sizes. except for the header height. its a static 100px

Comment: At first sight, your code doesn't really seem to center the div as I intended to do. It adds 10% padding to left/right in the header, corresponding to 10% margin left/right in the body. I don't prefer this, because on a high resolution, the page will become stretched (therefore I use pixels). I haven't seen many pages doing this either...

Comment: Size now in pixel, (not responsive anymore)

Comment: Thanks, but the question was regarding leverage of the outer wrapper. This solution poses the same problem, ie. both header / body elements need to be resized repeatedly on every media query. Anyhow, it doesn't appear to be possible to delegate responsiveness to the wrapper from the inner header. A pity. The simplest solution to avoid code repetition is still a class so it seems. Anyhow thanks for the efforts.